# .htaccess is ignoring url ending with ".com"

Tags: .htaccess

I am using this line in `.htaccess` to get all tabs in URL:

```
(...)
RewriteRule ^pok(.*)?/?$ index.php?url_tabs=$1 [L,QSA]
(..)
```

If in URL the last tab is a domain with `.com`, `.htaccess` rules are ignored.
But if I use `.pt`, `.it`, or anything else it works fine.

Works fine with URLs like:

- `example.com/pok/oij`
- `example.com/pok/uuu.pt`
- `example.com/pok/aaa.it`

But if I use:

- `example.com/pok/eee.com`

`.htaccess` rules are ignored.

Chat GPT gave this answer:

```
RewriteCond ^api(.*)\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^api(.*)\.com$ $1\.com/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^api(.*)?/?$ index.API.php?url_tabs=$1 [L,QSA]
```

But it didn't work.

Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: You need to include your complete `.htaccess` file. And to what URL are you expecting that to be rewritten? There’s nothing “wrong” with the snippet you’ve posted (although the regex is a bit “vague” given your example URLs). More likely a conflict with other directives. Without more information there is no reason a “.com” in the URL should be treated differently to any other 4 char sequence. What did you use to prompt ChatGPT? The first rule in ChatGPT’s “response” doesn’t even make sense?

Comment: Hi @MrWhite thank you for your answer. It seems that server interprets this like a file when URL ends with ".com". And because the "file" doesn't exist this command is ignored. I am stil trying to understand this...

Comment: This could be an issue with a mod_security rule / firewall? "because the "file" doesn't exist this command is ignored" - from what you've posted this command should be processed for both file and non-file requests. If there is a server security module/proxy/firewall intercepting these requests then your `.htaccess` file is likely being bypassed entirely.